# Подключение к странице HP

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha, captcha

Доброго времени суток!

Есть страница для проверки гарантии ноутбуков\принтеров\роутеров HP: https://support.hp.com/us-en/checkwarranty

Необходимо получить результат проверки. Для примера можно использовать это серийный номер: CND4358NV5

Есть 2 проблемы:

1. Когда получаю результат, ответ приходит не от серийного номера, а от номера продукта. То есть, где то на пути к результату происходит сначала поиск номера продукта и потому уже гарантии.
2. В куки и url есть captha_token, который страница тоже генерирует. Есть ли возможность обойти каптчу или же получать каждый раз при проверке этот токен?

И общий вопрос по решению проблемы - возможно ли все это сделать на PHP с использованием curl? Или же необходимы дополнительные библиотеки?

Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: рекапчу никак не обойти, ищи api

Comment: @Jean-Claude а есть ли оно там? Я новичок в этом деле, буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: https://developers.hp.com/

Comment: @Jean-Claude к сожалению на странице написано что API на данный момент не доступно :(